# GetContext() is not working

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm using regular JS (I know it isn't the best, but I'm a beginner)

So I'm writing code for a canvas project. However when using the getContext() function the JS console says

> Uncaught TypeError: canvas.getContext is not a function
>       at master.js:4

I've looked around and found that nothing has fixed my problem.

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('myCanvas');
console.log(canvas);
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
console.log(context);
```

The HTML is this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="master.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas class="myCanvas">Your browser doesn't support HTML canvas</canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements. Thus, it does not have the method you are looking for. Try the following:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('myCanvas')[0];
console.log(canvas);
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
console.log(context);
```

Your code is also stored in the HTML head, so your canvas element will not be found. Either put your `<script>` tag in the HTML `<body>` tag or set a function inside `document.onload` as follows:

```
document.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('myCanvas')[0];
  console.log(canvas);
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  console.log(context); 
}
```

Comment: Tried doing that, but now I'm getting the error:  _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined
    at master.js:3`_

Comment: That means the array is empty. Put your code in the HTML body or in document.onload. I will update my answer to reflect this.